# Python Scrapy - Issues with scraping data that is commented out

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

After hours troubleshooting, I finally was able to determine that the reason I couldn't scrape this data is because the most vital data is being commented out, and js must be loading it.   A "print response" does actually see it, but scrapy will not pull that data.

[image: Scrapy Issues]

Comment: what did you try? Did you use Google to search how to get comment from HTML using ie. `xpath` ?

Comment: using Google right now I found that in xpath you can use `comment()`. But maybe you get it as text and you will need to parse it (ie. using class `Selector()` in `scrapy` or module like `BeatifulSoup`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xpath` has `comment()` to get comment.

But it gives comment as normal text and you have to remove `<!--` and `-->` and parse it to search inside this `HTML`. In `scrapy` you can use class `Selector()` to parse it.

---

Minimal working code

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector

sel = Selector(text='''
<div>
<!--
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner">Hello World</div>
</div>
-->
</div>''')

comment = sel.xpath('//comment()').get()
print(comment)

#html = comment.replace('<!--', '').replace('-->', '')
html = comment[4:-3]
print(html)

sel = Selector(text=html)

divs = sel.xpath('//div').getall()
print(divs)
```

Result:

```
<!--
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner">Hello World</div>
</div>
-->

<div class="outer">
<div class="inner">Hello World</div>
</div>

['<div class="outer">\n<div class="inner">Hello World</div>\n</div>', '<div class="inner">Hello World</div>']
```

Comment: Whta is this line?  html = comment[4:-3]

Comment: it gets substring - without 4 chars at the beginning (`<!---`) and without 3 chars at the end (`-->`). BTW: next time simply use `print()` - `print(comment)` and `print(comment[4:-3])` - to see differences and you will not have to ask :)

Comment: My problem was it wasn’t a single block.  There were servers dozen commented sections.  But this pointed me in the right direction and I got it.  Thanks!

Comment: if you use `.get_all()` instead of `.get()` then you get list with all comments.